# How to fix Virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have tried to install `pip install virtualenv` but it said `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable` and that the

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python312\site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.8)
```

then I tried to type `virtualenv env` but it says `'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

How can I fix this??

Comment: try `py -m venv path/and/name/of/env` according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)